# File isn’t being read properly after being sent from the client?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to get an audio file from my user's microphone, and when I try to send it over to my server to download it keeps erroring.

Here's my js code to get the audio

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true})
      .then(stream => {handlerFunction(stream)})


            function handlerFunction(stream) {
            rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            rec.ondataavailable = e => {
              audioChunks.push(e.data);
              if (rec.state == "inactive"){
                let blob = new Blob(audioChunks,{type:'audio/mpeg-3'});
                recordedAudio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                recordedAudio.controls=true;
                recordedAudio.autoplay=true;
                var data = new FormData()
                data.append('file', blob, 'file')
                sendData(data)
              }
            }
          }
        function sendData(data) {
            fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/test',{
                method: 'POST',
                body: data
            })
        }
```

and my python code:

```
 if request.method == "POST":
        files = request.files
        file = files.get('file')
        print(file.content)
    return render_template('test.html')
```

and here's the trace:

```
  File "C:\Users\Rohan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Rohan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Rohan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
0, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Rohan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "main.py", line 24, in test2
    print(file.content)
  File "C:\Users\Rohan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\datastructures.py", line 3095, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.stream._file, name)
AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'content'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, all I needed to do was do `file.read` and not `file.content`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your trying to send a file stream back to the client which I don't think is supported by flask. Use the documentation for future reference.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/

also. Why isn't is not a question. try: file not being read after being sent.

Comment: I’m not trying to send anything back to the client, but from the client to the server.